# C# Sync two identical DataSets over a Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, dataset

What is the most effective way to sync two identically structured DataSets using a Web Service?

The design I use at the moment is simple without a Web Service. All data iscached on the Client, and it will only update data from the MySQL database if an update has been done, this is determined by a timestamp.

If possible I want to keep the same simple design, but add a Web Service in the middle, to allow easier access to the database over our limited VPN.

Best Regards, John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one heck of a question, but something I'm doing myself too. Easiest way I guess would be to add a "saved version" property. If it really is a simple design then you could just re-write only the DAL code to get things working for a web service. In fact, if the WSDL is done right, you may only need to make very minor adjustments (especially if the DB was previously designed using EF).

You say you want to sync two datasets simultaneously, but the question I guess is why? And which two? Do you have two web services, or are you wanting to sync data to both the local cache and the online web service (MSSQL db?) simultaneously?

Comment: I didn't realize how small the changes I had to do was. I just needed that nudge, thanks a lot. ;)